# 2-3-4 Tree Explanation

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

How would I implement a bottom-down insertion of a 2-3-4 tree in java?

Comment: It depends on the implementation of your tree, certainly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a pretty succinct explanation on the Wikipedia page:

[Insertion into a 2-3-4 Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-3-4_tree#Insertion)

I hate for the answer to just be a link, but this has been discussed to death elsewhere, and 5 seconds on Google would have found you the answer even faster than asking here.

Comment: I believe this is top-down insertion

Comment: Bottom-down insertion doesn't make any sense though. You're starting at the bottom of the tree, and progressing downward? It's like starting at 0 and counting down.